# Output edited shortcode content, not return it

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

is it possible somehow to execute / print content in a WordPress shortcode filter, not return it? I mean, shortcode functions in general return output, but do not print. If I tell my shortcode function to print, it outputs the worked trough shortcode content right in the beginning of all content and I don not have any possibility to work with it any more.

I really hope, someone can help me, if someony has understood what I mean ;)

Best regards, .wired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy! Use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).

```
ob_start(); // content is no longer output but is captured internally
echo 'buffered output'; // business as usual
$output = ob_get_contents(); // pass captured content to variable and
// terminate output buffering (echo beyond this point prints again)
return $output; // or play with it some more
```

PHP rules!

Comment: i DID think about buffering :D but somehow I had a thinking error because I thought I would have to end the buffering not inside of the shortcode function but after WordPress filtered the content. But I was wrong and really appreciate Your help, thank You!